# JQuery input[type=date] selector

Tags: jquery, html, date, input

I have an input with the type set as "date" (html5):

```
<input id="Employee_hireDate" class="pickDate" type="date" name="Employee[hireDate]" value="Hire Date" />
```

When I view the raw source, the type is set as date.  However, in Chrome Developer Tools it is not displayed.  And when I run:

```
alert($('#Employee_hireDate').attr('type'));
```

It shows the input type as undefined.  I'm using Google Chrome v15.

Does anyone have an idea of why JQuery can't find the selector?

Logan

Comment: Must be Chrome v15 specific problem. It's working fine with Chrome v13.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/knQpm/ (Chrome 15.0.865.0 dev, Linux __ 2.6.38-11-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 19:02:55 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should not do this, this way. HTML5 date has some very specific UI and a very specific API. For example the following code http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/EAZPN/ does not work in Opera and it won't be working in Chrome or any other browser, if the browser has implemented type="date" fully.

If you want to make this somehow workable, you have to remove the date and replace it with type text. Additionally you have to make sure, that you always use/generate date-value in the following format YYYY-MM-DD.

There are a lot of other things to make this really good. I have made a small example using [webshims lib](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html#Forms-forms-ext), which you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/VNuct/.

Webshims lib will hide your original type="date" input and creates a nameless new one, to mimic the visual implementation of a datepicker. It also transfers the input's value from one input to another and transforms this value into the right format. It also gives you the full HTML5 date API:

for example:

```
$('#Employee_hireDate').prop('valueAsNumber', 1315267200000);
$('#Employee_hireDate').prop('valueADate');
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm using the JQuery Tools date picker (because it looks awesome) for this input field.  The format is in, like you say YYYY-MM-DD.  You're saying if I want to use and external date picker (not the browsers) to use type text?

Comment: Well this gives the answer, why you don't see this. jQuery Tools date picker removes the type="date" in browsers, which have "minimal" type="date" support, to not conflict with the UI. So it won't return type=date in Chrome/Opera etc. anymore.

Comment: ugg, that's annoying.  I had no idea.  Thanks for answering the question!

Comment: but if i have to use the native datepicker only , then whats the solution , cause its the requirement of the hybrid application targeting android n ios

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the JSFiddle from RC's comment, and switch versions of jQuery around, you'll find you only get the correct answer ("date") with jQuery 1.6.2 or later. Make sure you're using the latest version of jQuery!

Comment: Thanks Domenic.  I'm using version 1.6.2 exactly.  Let me go play around with jfiddle.

Comment: If you change the script location to HEAD, that's the error I'm getting - undefined.  However, my script is being loaded at the END of the document.  So it SHOULD work as advertised?

Comment: The weird thing is that type="text" works fine, it's only if I change it to type="date".

Comment: i am using jquery-1.10.2 , its not fetching the value from input type='text' , its giving undefined everytime