# populate input date field with json data

Tags: json, date

My date field just doesn't seem to populate the date field with data from my json.  Is there something I'm missing?

JSON

```
[{"event_id":"72","event_title":"Shopping day","event_date":"2014-02-10 00:00:00"}]
```

APPENDING...

```
$.each(data, function(key, val){

                                                    // for populating edit event form
                                                    $('#event_idField').attr('value', val.event_id);
                                                    $('#event_titleField').attr('value', val.event_title);
                                                    $('#event_dateText').text(val.event_date);
                                                    $('#event_dateField').attr('value', val.event_date);

     });
```

FORM

```
<form id="callUpdateEventForm">
                    </br><input name="event_id" id="event_idField" type="hidden" >
                    <input type="text" name="event_title" id="event_titleField" placeholder="Event Title"/>
                    </br>
                    <!--<div id="event_dateText"></div>-->
                    <input type="date" name="event_date" id="event_dateField" value="" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
                    </br>

                    <a href"#" button id="updateEventButton"  data-role="button" data-theme="f">Update</a>
                 </form>


                            });
```

Comment: is there any specific reason to use type="date" ? you can also go and try with type="text"

Comment: Sorry, I thought that would be clear.  I need users to be able to easily select a new date, instead of manually typing it in.

Comment: you can use jquery date picker . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297554/jquery-inputtype-date-selector  Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hardikbhalani89/3wXvZ/

Comment: It has to work on phonegap so wanted to use the native date field type